# Which is the best centralized logging methodologies suitable to implement and maintain for managing containers on AWS ECS?

Tags: logging, containers, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, elk

We are moving to containers on AWS using ECS. So, I am looking for some suggestions regarding centralized logging. Can someone suggest me which is the best and efficient way to go for application and container logging on ECS?

Some of them like:
 1. ELK Stack
 2. awslog driver
 3. Cloudwatch etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out which solution is the best, but you can choose the one fitting your CURRENT context(including team size, skill sets, log volume, budget and so on).

- CloudWatch Logs. It's the simplest one. You can use `awsdriver` to deliver your logs to CloudWatch logs.

  - Pros:

    - You don't need maintain the log service. Your team can dedicate to your business development
    - The log service can be scaled out out of box
    - Pay as you go
    - Good integration with S3(for archiving), Analytics solution(use Glue/Athena for occasionally searching archived logs)
  - Cons:

    - UI/UX of CloudWatch Logs is not bad
    - There is no powerful dashboard(comparing to `Kibana`)
    - Logs insights works for most cases
    - The data ingestion fee of CloudWatch logs is expensive if the logs volume is massive
  - Conclusion: CloudWatch Logs is particularly very good solution for startup team to enable logs/alarming quickly without maintaining the infra
- EFK stack(Fluentd/Fluent bit/Elastic search/Kibana). You can use logger driver [firelens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html) to deliver your logs to ES, then use Kibana as dashboard.

  - Pros:

    - Leverage the sophisticated EFK solution with powerful dashboard
    - Data ingestion fee is free if you set up the container and ES in same AZ
  - Cons:

    - Your team should have experts on ES/Kibana skills
    - You have to maintain the infra of ES/Kibana to scale out/in when necessary
- Other PaaS services, such as `Splunk`

Also you have realtime analysis requirements for your logs, you also can use [firelens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html) to deliver your logs to stream(such as `Kinesis`, `MKS`) for realtime processing.

In a word, you have to make a tradeoff to choose a best-fit solution based on the priorities of your contexts.